# How do your reproduce this image with tkiz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can someone help me reproducing this image using tikz?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! hat you try so far?

Comment: **@close-voters:** Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use. Also, if you downvote or **vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why you did so, but wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close.**

Comment: I voted to close (too broad) after an answer was provided (to avoid too many random answers being thrown at the question). If the question is closed and updated with a minimal example or more specificity, I'd vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 5):

You can start with this code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mymatrix/.style={
        matrix of nodes, 
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={minimum width=8mm, draw},
        row 2/.style={%
            nodes={draw=none}},
    },
    ]
    \matrix[mymatrix] (A1) {|[fill=violet!30, label=left:$A$]|5&2&4&6&|[fill=green]|1&3\\1&2&3&4&5&6\\};
    \draw[rounded corners,<->] (A1-1-1.north)--+(0,5mm)-|(A1-1-5.north);
    \matrix[mymatrix, below=5mm of A1] (A2) {|[label=left:$A$]|1&|[fill=violet!30]|2&4&6&5&3\\1&2&3&4&5&6\\};
    \draw[rounded corners,<->] ([xshift=-2mm]A2-1-2.north)--+(0,5mm)-|([xshift=2mm]A2-1-2.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is another start.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=.6]

\begin{scope}
\fill[magenta] (0,0) rectangle +(1,1);
\fill[green] (4,0) rectangle +(1,1);
\draw (0,0) grid (6,1);
\foreach \i/\itext/\itextb in 
{1/5/1,2/2/2,3/4/3,4/6/4,5/1/5,6/3/6}
\path (\i-.5,.5) node{\itext} +(-90:1) node{\itextb};
\draw[stealth-stealth,rounded corners] 
(.5,1)--++(90:.5)--++(0:4)--++(-90:.5);
\path (0,1) node[left]{$A$};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=-2.5cm]
\fill[magenta] (1,0) rectangle +(1,1);
\draw (0,0) grid (6,1);
\foreach \i/\itext/\itextb in 
{1/1/1,2/2/2,3/4/3,4/6/4,5/5/5,6/3/6}
\path (\i-.5,.5) node{\itext} +(-90:1) node{\itextb};
\draw[stealth-stealth,rounded corners] 
(1.25,1)--++(90:.5)--++(0:.5)--++(-90:.5);
\path (0,1) node[left]{$A$};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```